# Cluster Points on spatial network in R/QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, clustering, network, geometric-network

I am searching for a method for clustering spatial points along spatial lines. 
The points are connected to the lines.

I tried nearest neighbour clustering and gProject/gInterpolate from the rgeos package. As you can see in the image, both results have the same problem: the clustering along lines doesn't make sense. In the image below, the point colours visualize the different clusters.

[image: false clustering along line]

Is there a solution in R or in QGIS to cluster the points by their location on a line/network?

Comment: Compute the distance between all pairs of points along the line network and feed that distance matrix into a clustering algorithm. How to compute distances along line networks is a separate question which may already have been answered.